# XPages Runtime optimized Javascript and CSS resources is not working

Tags: javascript, css, runtime, xpages, aggregator

For some time we have not been able to use the "Use runtime optimized JavaScript and CSS resources" feature because the aggregated JS and CSS links are always broken. When I inspect with the F12 IE developer tool, the CSS files just do not load. When I look at script, the aggregated JS file returns "Could not find file".

This issue only occurs when there are two or more JS or CSS resources that get aggregated. If it is only one resource (no aggregation), the link works.

I do notice that aggregated "internal" JS files are successfully found and loaded. It is just the ones within the app that are not found. This problem is consistent amongst all apps, which leads me to think this might be a server issue, perhaps a setting that was missed.

Other info: This problem existed in 8.5.3 and it still exists in Domino 9.0.1FP3. All users use IE 7 or higher. By "internal" JS files, I am referring to those files Domino loads when, for example, I request dojo modules. The path for these is "https://serverpath/xsp/.ibmxspres/.mini/dojo/..."

My db-specific resources, when aggregated, are "/dbpath/xsp/.ibmxspres/.js/..." and "/dbpath/xsp/.ibmxspres/.css/...".

If anyone has some suggestions on what the cause might be, I would appreciate hearing from you.

Comment: Are you using Dynamic Content component?

Comment: Hi Serdar. No, we are not using that control. I could create a blank XPage with nothing more than two custom JS resources and I would still have this problem.

Comment: Dynamic Content has such a problem. Maybe it helps looking at the way how it loads those resources. What happens in dynamic content is that When XSP loads the content after the page loads; If the inner facet has an additional CSS, (within a link tag) it does not get loaded by the browser. IE does not respect CSS out of head tag.

Comment: Also, keep in mind, resource aggregation does not work for partial refreshes (As far as I understood, this is not the case you have though)

Comment: As to your last comment, you are correct...I am only concerned about how resources get loaded when the full page is loaded. As for the issue with Dynamic Content, thanks. I will keep an eye for that in the future if I use that control.

Comment: "When I inspect with the F12 IE developer tool, the CSS files just do not load": does the server return 404? also, do you have any internet site rules that might conflict?

Comment: Hi Per - Yes, server does return 404. I don't believe we have any internet site rules, but I am checking with the admin.

Comment: Admin says there are no internet site rules in place at this time.

Comment: Is this behind a proxy of any sort? Many proxies will break with these URLs for one reason or another: double-escaping characters, too-long URLs, not proxying non-.nsf URLs, etc.

Comment: Hi Jesse - Yes, I am pretty sure we are behind a proxy.

Comment: Update: Server is definitely behind proxy, though the proxy is not doing anything particularly special. Also, we do in fact have internet site documents for the server, but they are database-specific. Lastly, and most importantly, I tried this on our test server and it does not have the same problem. The BIG difference is that it does not use Siteminder like the other server does and Siteminder is bad about messing with the url. I will do further tests with this and update this post tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be the DSAPI filter used with Siteminder. When the filter (DominoWebAgent.dll) file is removed, the problem goes away. As we are going away from Siteminder soon, we will just wait to use the aggregation tool. Thank you to each person who offered their thoughts on this issue.